# Change/Create permissions for a folder

Tags: permissions, directory, users, group, bind

How can I create (if the folder is new) or change (if the folder was already existent) permissions for a folder?

In particular, I want to create a subdirectory in `/etc/bind/` where I can put the  `named_dump.db` file, so I've to create the new directory with write permission for `bind` user and group.
First of all, is it right?
And if I want to change `/etc/bind/` permissions and save there `named_dump.db`?

Answer (score 2):

Normally as `root`:

```
mkdir /etc/bind
chown bind:bind /etc/bind
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir /etc/bind
chown bind:bind /etc/bind
chown bind:bind /etc/bind/named_dump.db
```

Should do the trick. The last command should done after `named_dump.db` is created or copied into place. You need to do this as root, or if sudo is implemented on your distribution using sudo if you are in the sudoers group.